# Object vs array result

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my **search filter** *(FormBuilder)* to return a list of filtering results, I have a form with a relation to an object *(multiple checkbox)*. It doesn't work.
I think I have a problem in my **repository** to get an **array vs object result.**

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use AdminBundle\Entity\Products;
use AdminBundle\Form\ProductsType;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('category', 'entity', array(
               'class' => 'AdminBundle:Category',
               'label' => false,
               'choice_label' => 'name',
               'required' => false,
               'expanded' => true,
               'placeholder' => 'Tous',
               'multiple' => true
           ))

           // ...
       ;
```

This is my repository:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Repository;

class ProductsRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function ListAll($data)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')->orderBy('a.updated','DESC');

        // CATEGORY
        if($data['category'] !== null)
        {
            $query
                ->innerJoin('a.category', 'cat')
                ->andWhere('cat.id = :catid')
                ->setParameter('catid', $data['category'])
            ;

            /*
            $query
                ->leftJoin('a.category', 'category')
                ->setParameter('category', $data['category'])
            ;
            */
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

This repository works for just a single select: `multiple => false`.  When I set `multiple => true`, I get an SQL violation about object vs. array.

How can I deal with the repository for multiple checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You must use ChoiceType instead of entityType

```
class CategoryRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
public function getForSearch()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('category');

    $qb->orderBy('category.name');
    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    $results = $query->getResult();
    $categories = array();

    foreach ($results as $category) {
        $categories[$category->getName()] = $category->getId();
    }

    return $categories;
}
```

In form

```
$categories = $em->getRepository(Category::class)->getForSearch();

 ->add('categories', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => $categories,
            'required' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Select',
        ))
```

And in controller :

```
if ($search_form->isSubmitted() && $search_form->isValid()) {
        $data = $search_form->getData();
        $em->getRepository(Product::class)->ListAll($data);
```

I also think we can use a data transformer but I do not how to do that

Comment: my object is category, how to deal in my repository

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'numero 2' ORDER BY e0_.updated DESC' at line 1

Comment: getForSearch or getForList ?

Comment: products vs product ?    little mystake too, in the form choices =>$product, and after upstairs $products

Comment: i think there's a problem in the scipt for the repository ?

Comment: @oliviertoppin I updated my answer because I have replace products by categories sorry for this

Comment: getRepository(Category::class)  vs getRepository('AdminBundle:category'), what is the best way?

Comment: @oliviertoppin it 's the same, Category::Class it's because I have a use App\Repo\Category... in the top of file

Comment: my problem when i run i see this error : Notice: Undefined variable: em --- error in this line :$categories = $em->getRepository(Category::class)->getForSearch();

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 8 ORDER BY e0_.updated DESC' at line 1

Comment: it's working with this :   $categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AdminBundle:Category')->getForSearch();
but when select more than 2 options, it's going down...

Comment: the 2 solutions gives the same problems. not working with multiple selections